# how to make json format in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

how do i create a json object similar to this in PHP?

```
{"id":1, "id":2, "id":3, "id":4, "id":5}
```

My data

```
$dataArr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$listArr = [];
foreach ($dataArr as $key => $value) {
 $listArr[] = array('id' => $value);
}

$xx = (object) $listArr;

$json = json_encode($xx);

echo "Json: ".$json  ."n";
```

Comment: That JSON will result in only 1 entry https://3v4l.org/JQMlH and what is the problem with what your code produces?

Comment: first code line is wrong ; keys are the same, there will be only one value in the object litteral (don't mistake json and object litterals)

Comment: `echo json_encode(array_map(function($v) { return ['id'=>$v]; }, $dataArr));`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert array to Object.

```
$dataArr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$listArr = [];
foreach ($dataArr as $key => $value) {
 $listArr[] = ['id' => $value];
}

$json = json_encode($listArr);

echo "Json: ".$json  ."n";
```

Output should be:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5}]
```

P.S. Your example is not correct, you can not create object with 5 same keys.

Comment: i see. i think we can make an object with the same keys.
thanks bro